# Heavy-Tailed Data

Tags: normality-assumption, fat-tails

I'm currently trying to perform a point-biserial correlation on my data, but can't seem to get the continuous data to follow a normal distribution.

I've looked into other answers on this website and thus far I've tried Lambert, cube root, square root, asinh, etc.

What further steps should I take to try and transform this data?

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. What is your question?

Comment: (1) This is an extremely *light* - tailed distribution.  (2) Why do you think your data must follow a Normal distribution?  After all, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient) on the point-biserial correlation coefficients mentions Normality in only one passage--in which it suggests using a different correlation coefficient for that case!

Comment: I had seen a few sources where they assumed normality ( ie. https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/point-biserial-correlation-using-spss-statistics.php), and from my courses in statistics the correlations we covered assumed normality before assessing the relationship. Thank you for pointing this out though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't take *any* further steps because point-biserial (PBS) correlation does not assume that the data are normally distributed.  This makes sense, because PBS is mathematically equivalent to Pearson correlation, and that doesn't assume normality either.

PBS is affected by the balance of the variable - that is, are there equal numbers of subject in each of the two groups?  If not, then the range of PBS is limited.

And, while PBS does not assume normality, it is affected by outliers. That doesn't violate assumptions, it just may mean that the PBS is not what you want. It doesn't look like you have outliers (as @whuber points out, you have a light tailed distribution), but the QQ plot isn't ideal for looking for outliers.